# Wordpress on a subdirectory of Laravel - Wordpress pretty permalinks inner page shows laravel

Tags: permalinks, urls, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I read lots of discussions about this and found no solution. I have a Laravel web app and added a Wordpress site in a subdirectory. This is what my `.htaccess` looks like within the `public` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)


# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The `.htaccess` which resides within `public->blog` looks like this:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here's the problem:

If I use the plain permalinks, everything works fine. If I use any other type of permalink it adds `index.php` to the URL and shows me the Laravel app.
The permalinks adds the `index.php` in the permalinks page:
[image]

The funny thing is, if I choose the `post name` permalink with the `%postname%` in it, the URL is:

```
http://localhost:8000/blog/postname/
```

and I see the laravel app, but the same URL with the admin (`http://localhost:8000/blog/wp-admin/`) or any other admin pages, works fine.

I really don't want to have to use ugly permalinks here.

Is there a solution?

FYI - as you can see on the screenshot, the site is currently on localhost using `XAMPP`.

Comment: Does your Laravel app route correctly, using "pretty" URLs and without `index.php` in the URL?

Comment: yes. Completely. Also, as mentioned, the first option (plain permalinks) is without index.php and works fine.

Comment: "The `.htacess` which resides within `public->blog`" - To clarify, you have spelt the `.htaccess` (2 c's) filename correctly? (I've since corrected that with my "edit" - but just realised that that would also explain your current problem!)

Comment: Yes, it's spelled correctly

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? The fact that the admin panel is showing `index.php` in the example URL would seem to suggest that it has been unable to detect a suitable rewriting module (ie. mod_rewrite)? "the first option (plain permalinks) is without index.php and works fine" - Incidentally, that wouldn't need `index.php` anyway, even without mod_rewrite (providing the `DirectoryIndex` is set correctly).

Comment: @MrWhite I did not resolve this. My only options currently are to either use ugly URLs or move the site outside of Laravel (i.e a subdomain)

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found a solution.
I was using a local XAMPP installation and there was no way around it.
Though when I uploaded the site to a live server it worked fine.
I hope this helps someone in the future.
I've seen a lot of people with the same issue but never saw a solution...

Comment: Could you expand on the solution you found?

Comment: I basically explained all there is to explain in the answer. When I uploaded the site to a live server and changed the permalinks, it worked just fine. Just like any other Wordpress site.

Comment: I will up-vote the answer because I have the same behavior. Moving to a live server fixed the issue I had on locahost with the permalinks.